# Close ring on a mesh passing through given points

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, geometry, mesh

Suppose I've some points on a mesh (2+) that can be anywhere on the mesh, suppose for example these (ignore the small points, just consider the sphere):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDzW3.png
(sorry can't put directly the image)

But note that they can be everywhere

How can I get a closed ring of points that goes around the mesh and include the given points? 
I have access to both neighbours and neighbouring faces for each point on the mesh.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please clarify this: _closed ring of points that goes around the mesh and include the given points_ eventually with an additional image?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that ring goes on existing mesh edges. Than mesh edges can be seen as a graph and problem is similar to [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) on given vertices.

TSP is hard (slow) to solve. I suppose that points positions approximate circle, than it is probably enough to use simpler algorithm. Start from one point and find closest of input points (Dijkstra's). Than start from that point and find closest of not visited points. Repeat that until path returns to starting point.